# VB 2005 app failing to start pscp subprocess

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, process, .net-2.0

I've got a VB2005 application written by a previous coder. I had to move it to a new windows 7 box, since the xp box it was hosted on had catastrophic hard drive failure. It worked fine on the xp box, but it fails on the windows 7 box.

More specifically, I've tracked it back to a specific subsection. It uses the Process library to start pscp, the putty scp command line tool. It has a timer to wait 400 seconds for the process to close, otherwise it stops the process and reports an error.

Unfortunately, on windows 7 it doesn't seem to even start the process, because it does not wait the specified 400 seconds, nor does it report the other error it would give if pscp did start, but failed. Is there a compatibility issue with the process library, or is it some configuration issue?

*Update:*

Alright, after more testing I've determined that the subprocess is getting spawned, but the parent is not waiting for it to exit.

it seems the VB code `myProcess.WaitForExit(40000)` is not actually waiting  until the process exits. Is this because it can't 'see' the process and believes it *has* exited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a face palm worthy moment, it seems. One of the other devs made a change to this thing, and I grabbed the version he specified, from the bin/debug folder. Unfortunately, his setup did not build both a release version and a debug version at the same time. And like an idiot, I didn't bother to check the time stamp on it, and I didn't realize that the debug version had not been updated.

The version in the bin/debug folder was several months old and did not actually work. So all the changes we made trying to fix it weren't being used. I've learned a few valuable lessons here,

1. Check that your grabbing the most recent executable
2. Even if the previous dev didn't set up a repo, look into doing so
3. Always clone a working setup, to avoid having this happen in the first place